# How to migrate a ZFS filesystem to use compression?

Tags: filesystems, storage, zfs, solaris

Question at the bottom.

I have several ZFS file system I would like to use ZFS compression, but since enabling the compression will only affect new data written to the file system, I would like to write a script that can migrate file systems, so all data is compressed.

This is my test attempt

```
du -h /tmp/dump.txt

zfs create -p tank3/xtest1/fs
cp /tmp/dump.txt /tank3/xtest1/fs
zfs list | grep xtest

zfs create tank3/xtest2
zfs set compression=lzjb tank3/xtest2
zfs inherit compression tank3/xtest2

zfs snapshot tank3/xtest1/fs@snap
zfs send tank3/xtest1/fs@snap | zfs receive tank3/xtest2/fs
zfs get compression tank3/xtest2/fs
zfs list | grep xtest

zfs destroy -r tank3/xtest1
zfs destroy -r tank3/xtest2


echo "test 2"

zfs create tank3/xtest2
zfs set compression=lzjb tank3/xtest2
zfs list | grep xtest

cp /tmp/dump.txt /tank3/xtest2
zfs list | grep xtest
zfs get compressratio tank3/xtest2

zfs destroy -r tank3/xtest2
```

which gives

```
344M    /tmp/dump.txt
tank3/xtest1                          575K  6.38T   288K  /tank3/xtest1
tank3/xtest1/fs                       288K  6.38T   288K  /tank3/xtest1/fs
NAME             PROPERTY     VALUE     SOURCE
tank3/xtest2/fs  compression  off       default
tank3/xtest1                          344M  6.38T   304K  /tank3/xtest1
tank3/xtest1/fs                       344M  6.38T   344M  /tank3/xtest1/fs
tank3/xtest2                          344M  6.38T   288K  /tank3/xtest2
tank3/xtest2/fs                       344M  6.38T   344M  /tank3/xtest2/fs
test 2
tank3/xtest2                          288K  6.38T   288K  /tank3/xtest2
tank3/xtest2                          288K  6.38T   288K  /tank3/xtest2
NAME          PROPERTY       VALUE  SOURCE
tank3/xtest2  compressratio  1.00x  -
```

In the first test would I have expected the replication would compress the data when creating `tank3/xtest2/fs` but newly created file systems does not inherit compression when using send/receive it seams.

In test 2 I can't see the 344MB file takes any space.

From what I can tell compression doesn't work.

**Question**

Why do I see these weird results?

And how should I migrate a not compressed file system to be compressed?

**Update**

Added `compressratio` property which shows that no compression have been done. `dump.txt` can be compressed to 190MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `dump.txt` is highly compressible it turns out, that zfs won't compress it for some reason.

Redoing my experiments again with other data, it turns out that send/receive will compress the data. Here I have set the compression on the zpool, so all file systems would inherit this. I also used Linux here, but that shouldn't matter.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/dat0/zpool1 bs=1M count=1000
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/dat0/zpool2 bs=1M count=1000
# service zfs-fuse restart
# zpool create zpool1 /mnt/dat0/zpool1 
# zpool create zpool2 /mnt/dat0/zpool2
# zfs set compression=on zpool1
# zfs create zpool1/fs1
# zfs create zpool2/fs2
# cp -r /etc/ /var/log /zpool2/fs2/
# zfs snapshot zpool2/fs2@snap
# zfs send zpool2/fs2@snap | zfs receive zpool1/fs2
# zfs get compressratio zpool1/fs2
NAME        PROPERTY       VALUE  SOURCE
zpool1/fs2  compressratio  4.75x  -
```

Comment: You're doing a disservice by not using lz4 compression.

Comment: I will use lz4, it is just that it requires irreversible changes to the zpool, so I can't do it on this host.

Comment: Compression is not an irreversible change.

Comment: From http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/LZ4+Compression   If you would like to enable LZ4 on a pool which doesn't have feature flags enabled, upgrade the pool first using the "zpool upgrade <poolname>" command. Please note that this will make your pool unimportable on systems which lack support for feature flags (e.g. Solaris 10, Oracle Solaris 11, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

**Copy the data.**

That is all.

There's a bunch of missing output in your examples, but it doesn't matter. The only thing you need to do to move data into a compressed filesystem is to rewrite the data either by copying it, moving it or populating a new filesystem.

Avoid the problem in future situations by enabling compression at the pool level so that it's inherited by new filesystems. Also, use `lz4` compression flag. [It's generally better](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/).

Comment: All the output should be there. I have copy/pasted everything. Can you figure out what I wrong with my test 2? Why doesn't it take up any space?

Comment: If the `dump.txt` is a highly compressible file, the results are just what are expected. The file takes only the space it takes in compressed form. So, copying the file compresses it.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Compressed `dump.txt` is 190MB and in `zfs list` before and after the copy, zfs shows 288k. It should have showed at least 190MB after.

Comment: It turns out that send/receive works. Please see any answer.

Comment: Link is dead. Can you update it?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The link to what?

Comment: @ewwhite The only link in your answer, but it appeared to be a temporary outage, so whatever.

Comment: it's outdated either way, today you likely wanna use `zstd` instead of `lz4`